# Remove Attributes onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make use of JQuery's remove attribute like this:

```
$('#rom-img_1').removeAttr('mouseover');
$('#rom-img_2').removeAttr('mouseout');
```

However, it does not remove the effects of the events as the events are still triggered on mouseover and on mouseout. I have tried adding "on" before the events names too but JQuery doesn't use it like that.

Why isn't this working and how can I remove those attributes.

This is a bit of the HTML:

```
<div onmouseout="$('#heart_401').css({'display':'none'});" onmouseover="$('#heart_401').css({'display':'block'});" id="row-img_11"></div>
```

Thanks all for any help

Comment: Once the browser parses them they're event handlers, maybe still attributes as well, depending on the browser...is not inserting them in the first place an option?

Comment: When I use firebug to remove the attributes it seems that the events are not triggered anymore, is this due to firebug or what should happen when remove attribute is applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#rom-img_1')
```

You've mis-spelled `row-img_11`. jQuery doesn't error this, you just get a selector result with no matches.

`removeAttr` of `onmouseover` works for me with this fixed, although you would generally want to avoid using inline event handler attributes like this.

Comment: Actually you are right, there is a mis-spelling  but not the extra one that was my type but the "rom" rather than "row"! Damn it! I don't know why someone neg repped you, but this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Never register event handlers by using onsomething in the html code. It makes your markup less readable and causes various problems (such as `this` not pointing to the element).

Always register them by using `$(...).mouseover(function() { /* yourcode */ })` or `$(...).bind('mouseover', function() { /* yourcode */ })`.

**Then you can easily remove the handlery by using `$(...).unbind('mouseover')`.**

Of course you can also use other handlers like *click* or *focus* instead of *mouseover*.

The reason why removeAttr doesn't work is that handlers aren't attributes. Internally they are turned into handlers and thus you cannot remove them by removing the attribute.
However, this might work:

```
$('#rom-img_1')[0].mouseover = function() {};
$('#rom-img_1')[0].mouseout = function() {};
```

Comment: The divs are generated dynamically and I will not know the id of the elements. In addition, this is a small project. I just need it working ! :)

Comment: I thought those were attributes i.e. onmouseout: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onmouseout

Answer (score 1):

To get and set mouseover and mouseout events in jQuery use `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()`.  Syntax as follows:

**Set (remove in this case):**

```
$("#row-img_11").mouseover("");
$("#row-img_11").mouseout("");
```

- http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/
- http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

To apply the methods to a group of divs:

```
$("div:contains('row-img')").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover("");
    $(this).mouseout("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just spell the id right, it works just fine:

```
$('#row-img_11').removeAttr('onmouseover').removeAttr('onmouseout');
```